# Highlight selected bar in different color in wpf

Tags: wpf, bar-chart, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF application where I have a bar chart.

By default the color of bar is steel blue.

I want a functionality where when a users selects a bar, it should be highlighted in a different color i.e. red to indicate that is the product referring to. Please guide me how can I achieve this.

Currently I have used the following columndatapoint style.

```html
    <Style
                x:Key="MyColumnDataPointStyle"
                TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="SteelBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
                    <Border
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Opacity="1"
                                x:Name="Root">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverHighlight"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                    To="0.6"
                                                    Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionHighlight"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                    To="0.6"
                                                    Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Shown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                    To="1"
                                                    Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                    To="0"
                                                    Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop
                                                    Color="#77ffffff"
                                                    Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop
                                                    Color="#00ffffff"
                                                    Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Border
                                        BorderBrush="#ccffffff"
                                        BorderThickness="1">
                                <Border
                                            BorderBrush="#77ffffff"
                                            BorderThickness="1"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Fill="Red" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Fill="White" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentControl
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedIndependentValue}"
                                            FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                <ContentControl
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the MVVM pattern I would create a ViewModel class for your ColumnDataPoint.
This ViewModel contains a bool property e.g. called IsActive.
You can then bind the bar's DataContext to that ViewModel and in your style you can set a DataTrigger bound to that property. 
To change that property you can create a command in your ViewModel which will be executed when clicking the bar

Here is a small example:

```
     <Rectangle Fill="SteelBlue"
                DataContext="{Binding YourViewModel}">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Chartreuse"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClickingBarCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     </Rectangle>
```

To use the "i" and "command" namespace you have to add

> xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
>                xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"

Hopefully this was helpful to you

cheers